c# call generic method from abstract class passing inheriting type
I'm going to explain better what I mean.
I think what I desire is not possibile, however I'll try.
I have a static class who have this method:
public static class BaseTypeID
{
    static ulong _id = 1;

    public static ulong NextID => _id++;
}

public static class TypeID<T> where T : class
{
    public static readonly ulong ID = 0;

    static TypeID()
    {
        ID = BaseTypeID.NextID;
    }
}

public static class Register
{
    public static void PrintType<T>(T passedVar) where T : AbstractType
    {
         Console.WriteLine(TypeID<T>.ID);
    }
}

I have the abstract class who call this method:
public abstract class AbstractType
{
    public void UseStaticMethod() => Register.PrintType(this);
}

And Inheriting class:
public class InheritingType : AbstractClass { }

Actually, if I do:
InheritingType myVar = new InheritingType();
myVar.UseStaticMethod();

it prints ID of AbstractClass instead InheritingType ID. Is there a way to call the InheritingType's ID without writing an override method?
Thank you so much

How about passedVar.GetType() instead of typeof(T)? Can you change PrintType?

@Sweeper I'm doing an easy way to reproduce my need. Actually the static method call a static generic class who needs the inheriting type so I cant use the passed variable :(

@Sweeper I added the other part. I thought it could made this too complicated to explain. I'm sorry.

Note that NextID => _id++ is not threadsafe, and it is generally expected that static methods should be thread safe. So I would consider Interlocked.Increment instead.

Also, a property should return the same value if you access it multiple times in a row (unless something else happens to change its value). Your NextID property should be a method. (DateTime.Now was later considered a mistake by the designers)

@canton7 I thought calling property with explicit name would be sufficient. I changed it to method, thank you!

@JonasH you're right, changed :)

It is technically possible if you dynamically dispatch PrintType,
public void UseStaticMethod() => Register.PrintType((dynamic)this);

But if you are only using TypeID<T> in this dynamic way, you should consider changing TypeID to be a non-generic and non-static class. Have it work with Type objects instead of generic type parameters.

Ah wow, I didn't thought using dynamic, thank you! No, it's quite never used in this dynamic way and I'm going to think if it would be better to don't implement this and going for a workaround with a few bigger memory usage instead of performance leak.

I can see two possible solutions: either use argument, not type T
public static class Register
{
    public static void PrintType<T>(T passedVar) where T : AbstractType
    {
         // We use passedVar (actual value), not declared type T 
         Console.WriteLine(passedVar.GetType());
    }
}

Or override UseStaticMethod() method:
public abstract class AbstractType
{
    public virtual void UseStaticMethod() => Register.PrintType(this);
}

public class InheritingType : AbstractType
{
    public override void UseStaticMethod() => Register.PrintType(this);
}


Do you think there is no other way instead override? Actually I can't use "GetType" cause I wrote and easy way to reproduce my need, but I have to use the "T" cause the static method calls a static generic class who needs the inheriting type so I cant use the passed variable :(

I added the other part. I thought it could made this too complicated to explain. I'm sorry.
